# TeX-file output another TeX-file

Tags: write

My problem, is to generate some `.tex`-file from within another `.tex`-file. The origin of problem is to extract some information from scientific paper, and create another `.tex`->`.pdf`-file with data about authors and so on.

My `MWE` now work with using `\string`, but if I want to create many lines in outputted `.tex`, it is easy to make a mistake. Is any simple solution?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
    %\usepackage{filecontents}
\makeatletter
\def\macroPass#1{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \else
    \def\macroPrint{#1}
    \fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}


\newwrite\regformfile
\newcommand\writeregformfile{%
    \immediate\openout\regformfile=data.tex
    \immediate\write\regformfile{
            \string\documentclass{article}^^J
            \string\begin{document}^^J
                \string\begin{center} \string\bfseries^^J
                     \string\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}^^J
                         \string\hline^^J
                        Field& \unexpanded\expandafter{\macroPrint}  \string\\  \string\hline^^J
                     \string\end{tabular}^^J
                 \string\end{center}^^J
             \string\end{document}
    }
}

\macroPass{To data.tex}
\writeregformfile
\end{document}
```

MWE  with `folecontents`, which is work incorrect.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}
    %\usepackage{filecontents}
\makeatletter
\def\macroPass#1{%
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    \else
    \def\macroPrint{#1}
    \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{filecontents*}{data.tex}
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
        \begin{center}\bfseries
            \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
                \hline
                Field& \macroPrint \\ \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{center}
    \end{document}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\macroPass{To data.tex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: see [fancyvrb](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) or [filecontents](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/filecontents) packages

Comment: Can't the information be put in a .tex file that is inputted in all your other documents ?

Comment: @touhami I know about this packages, but I did not see the possibility of parameters passing to filecontents in documentation

Comment: why all the \writes? you could write the whole thing with a single write (`^^J` makes a newline)

Comment: sorry it seems i am not understanding the question. Can you explain it a bit (if you think it's clear just don't care, it's my english)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, thanks. This it is simplifies the task, but \string is still here.

Comment: just put `\unexpanded{....}` around the whole thing.

Comment: It isn't clear why you can't just use `filecontents` (which doesn't need a package) the `\macroPass` command you define doesn't seem to be related in any way to the file writing?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do not completely understand your comment. I have add second MWE with filecontents, but it is does not work. Where is my mistake?

Comment: `{data.tex}` should be an argument to filecontents not to `\documentclass` then either filecontents needs to be at the start of the file, or use the filecontens package version

Comment: but what do you want `\macroPass{To data.tex}` to do? currently it just defines an unused macro, after the data.tex file is written out.

Comment: @David Carlisle {data.tex} - my stupied mistake. But I need to be \macroPrint expanded in data.tex to text from within \macroPass. My firs MWE work correct. You could to see the data.tex from it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cheat and use a different escape character for defining the macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T2A,T1]{fontenc}

\newcommand\macroPass[1]{%
  \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    \def\macroPrint{#1}%
  \fi
}

\newwrite\regformfile
\begingroup
\catcode`?=0 \catcode`\\=12
?endlinechar=`^^J
?gdef?writeregformfile{%
  ?immediate?openout?regformfile=data.tex%
  ?immediate?write?regformfile{%
    \documentclass{article}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{center} \bfseries
    \begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    Field & ?unexpanded?expandafter{?macroPrint} \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
  }%
}%
?endgroup%

\begin{document}

\macroPass{To data.tex}
\writeregformfile
\end{document}
```

The output file is as follows.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center} \bfseries
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
\hline
Field & To data.tex \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```